# regexp_substr: find the text before a given patern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to find the text before a given pattern. My main problem is when my text has many rows.

Here the example:

```
    SQL> with foo as
  2  (select '1 first test error log blabla ' k from dual
  3  union
  4  select '2 second test
  5  zz error log blablabla ' k from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(k,'.*error log',1,1) AS result_
  8         ,k from foo;
RESULT_                               K
------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
1 first test error log                1 first test error log blabla
zz error log                          2 second test
                                      zz error log blablabla
```

The result is false for the second rows.
It should be:

```
RESULT_                               K
------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
1 first test error log                1 first test error log blabla
2 second test                         2 second test
zz error log                          zz error log blablabla
```

I run this query on a 11.2 Oracle database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303), the 5th argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is:

> `match_parameter` is a text literal that lets you change the default matching behavior of the function.

Which has the [options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014):

> - `'n'` allows the period (`.`), which is the match-any-character character, to match the newline character. If you omit this parameter, then the period does not match the newline character.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9186f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( k ) AS
SELECT '1 first test error log blabla ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2 second test
zz error log blablabla ' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(k,'.*error log',1,1,'n') AS result_,
       k
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9186f/2/0)**:

```
|                RESULT_ |                              K |
|------------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1 first test error log | 1 first test error log blabla  |
| 2 second test          | 2 second test                  |
| zz error log           | zz error log blablabla         |
```

Comment: Beat me to it. `n` is used in oracle, the flag in most languages, however, is `s`.

Comment: Hi MTO, Thank for your answer. It's exactly what I wanted. I have just something to add to my query. It was not correct because regexp is greedy. So to avoid that if we have two time the pattern, we can add a ? to the search. It will be REGEXP_SUBSTR(k,'.*?error log',1,1,'n')